# Slow query in Eloquent using accessor

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a Model with an accessor that gets the last element related (through another table/model) with it. It comes in handy for individual queries but now I need to make a summary and the query takes way too long.

The model is called Device and it has the following accessor:

```
public function getPreviousDeviceAttribute()
    {
        if ($this->pos_id > 0){
            $pos = Pos::find($this->pos_id);
            $device = $pos->devices()->newPivot()->where([
                    ['device_id', '<', $this->id],
                    ['pos_id','=', $this->pos_id]
                ])->get()->sortByDesc('id')->first();
            return $device;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

From a Controller I need to query all the previous_device of a collection.

This is the query:

```
$c_pendientes = Device::whereNotNull('fecha_instalacion')
                ->whereNull('fecha_reversa')
                ->where('pos_id', '>', 0)
                ->where('customer_id', 1)
                ->get();

$pendientes = $this->seriesPendientes($c_pendientes);

public function seriesPendientes($pendientes)
    {
        $count = 0;

        foreach($pendientes as $device)
        {

            $prev = $device->previous_device;
            if($prev instanceof App\Device)
            {
                if(is_null($prev->fecha_reversa))
                {
                    $count++;

                }
            }
        }
        return $count;
    }
```

EDIT:

Attributes:

Device

```
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `serial` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `rotulo` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `code` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `cost_center` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `guia_recepcion` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `guia_reversa` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pep` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `modified_by` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `modified_on` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `fecha_recepcion` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `fecha_instalacion` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `fecha_reversa` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `status_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `location_id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `customer_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `str_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `model_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `pos_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `technician_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Pos

```
CREATE TABLE `pos` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `vigente` BLOB NOT NULL,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Relationship

```
CREATE TABLE `devices_pos` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `device_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `pos_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Comment: Please, post your database model to help people helping you :) at least the attributes of the tables related to the question. :)

Comment: Ok, just edited it.

Comment: You just want to count the "piendientes" ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling this getter for each item in a large collection, the `$pos = Pos::find($this->pos_id);` line will do one request for each item. You could avoid it by defining the following relation if it does not exist yet

```
public function pos()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Pos::class);
}
```

And then eager load this relation (one request for all the items) :

```
$c_pendientes = Device::with('pos')
                ->whereNotNull('fecha_instalacion')
                ->whereNull('fecha_reversa')
                ->where('pos_id', '>', 0)
                ->where('customer_id', 1)
                ->get();
```

You should probably eagder load pos.devices too like :

```
$c_pendientes = Device::with('pos')
                ->with('pos.devices')
                ->whereNotNull('fecha_instalacion')
                ->whereNull('fecha_reversa')
                ->where('pos_id', '>', 0)
                ->where('customer_id', 1)
                ->get();
```

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Remember I need to get the device related to the original one. It'd be good to just make one query from the controller and avoid the accessor but I'm not sure how the answer addresses that part of the problem.

Comment: Also the relationship at the beginning exists but it's a belongsToMany